# Time complexity of given code?

Tags: time-complexity

what is time complexity of this code:

```
for (i=1 to n)
   for (j=1 to i^2)
        if ((j mod i)==0)
               for (k=1 to j)
                   write ("*");
```

I find this relation between i, j and k:
for example n=4 so:

```
i      j             k
1      1-1           1  k  run for 1time
2      1-4           1,2,3,4  k run for 2 and 4 times
3      1-9           1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 k run for 3, 6 and 9 times
4      1-16          1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16 k run for 4, 8, 12 and 16 times
```

but i cant find its complexity

Answer (score 0):

occurrence of j mod i=0 can be taken as negligible as compare to large value of n. for the 1st two nested loop evidently the complexity being summation of pow(i,2) from 1 upto n. so we can take complexity as O(n^3).